# how to print some text and a function result on one line in python?

Tags: python, printing, python-3.6

I'm using python3.6. I'm trying to print some text and a result of a function on one line.

```
print("Type of partition:")
type_of_partition(partentry)
```

This gives me:

```
Type of partition:
FAT 16
```

but I want them on the same line as it looks friendly. I tried

```
print("Type of partition: ", type_of_partition(partentry))
```

this gives me:

```
Type of partition: None
FAT 16
```

I tried:

```
print("Type of partition: %s" % type_of_partition(partentry))
```

this gives me:

```
FAT 16
Type of partition: None
```

How can I put them together?

Comment: Use a space as your first prints end (it's newline by default). `print("Type of partition:", end=' ')`.

Comment: It looks like your `type_of_partition` method doesn't return a string and instead prints it directly. A better design would be to let it return something. Then, `print("Type of partition: %s" % type_of_partition(partentry))` would work.

Comment: ohhhhh yes right, this is what I did, my functions does print, not return.my bad. Thanks a million!

Comment: thank you sir, this is a nice approach as well @Kasramvd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `type_of_partition` function's `print result` to `return result`